# GroupBy in LINQ with string[] array

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone

I'm working on the database application which shows clear report of the transaction by its tags.

This is my old **database**.

```
Title      Amount       TagsReport (string[] array)
Food       5            "Hotel","Friends"
Food       6            "Hotel"
Family     8            "Hotel","Mobile"
Family     9            "Electricity"
Food       8            "Party"
```

I wish to generate the report like below:

**Desired Output:**

```
Percentage     Title             Amount
53%            Food              19
                  Hotel             11
                  Friends           5
                  Party             8

57%            Family            17
                 Hotel             8
                 Mobile            8
                 Electricity       9
```

I don't have enough knowledge on LINQ. So I face lot of trouble in this finding a perfect solution.

However I find this code to use,

```
var ReportingData = ReportListQuery
.Where(Item => Item.Category == "expense")
.GroupBy(item => item.Title)
.Select(itemGroup => new
{
    Percentage = Math.Round((itemGroup.Sum(item => item.Amount) / MonthExpense) * 100),
    ExpenseTitle = itemGroup.Key,
    ExpenseCalculation = itemGroup.Sum(item => item.Amount),
    TotalTagAmounts = itemGroup
    .SelectMany(item => item.TagsReport.Select(tag => new
    {
        Tag = tag,
        Amount = item.Amount
    }))
    .GroupBy(tagAmount => tagAmount.Tag)
    .Select(tagAmountGroup => new
    {
        Tag = tagAmountGroup.Key,
        TotalAmount = tagAmountGroup.Sum(tagAmount => tagAmount.Amount)
    })
});
```

And I got the output as I would like to have.

Now We've removed the title from our database. So db is now like,

```
Amount       TagsReport (string[] array)
5            "Hotel","Friends"
6            "Hotel"
8            "Hotel","Mobile"
9            "Electricity"
8            "Party"
```

Now I would group all transactions by its tags alone like below:

```
Amount       Title
19           Hotel
5            Friends
8            Mobile
9            Electricity
8            Party
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets much simpler with the new requirement.

If your data starts out like this:

```
var ReportListQuery = new []
{
    new { Amount = 5, TagsReport = new [] { "Hotel", "Friends" } },
    new { Amount = 6, TagsReport = new [] { "Hotel" } },
    new { Amount = 8, TagsReport = new [] { "Hotel", "Mobile" } },
    new { Amount = 9, TagsReport = new [] { "Electricity" } },
    new { Amount = 8, TagsReport = new [] { "Party" } },
};
```

Then this is the query you need:

```
var ReportingData =
    from report in ReportListQuery
    from tag in report.TagsReport
    group report.Amount by tag into gtags
    select new
    {
        Title = gtags.Key,
        Amount = gtags.Sum(),
    };
```

The result I get is this:

[image: result]

As a bit of a side note, in your original query you were working with integer math for the percentage figure. This doesn't work and would give you zero for each figure. You need to change this line:

```
Percentage = Math.Round((itemGroup.Sum(item => item.Amount) / MonthExpense) * 100),
```

to this:

```
Percentage = Math.Round(itemGroup.Sum(item => item.Amount) * 100.0m / MonthExpense),
```

That will make it use `decimal` rather than `int` and give you proper results.

Comment: Thanks a trillion first of all. I got following error when I use ReportingData.ToList(). 

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'System.String'. Actual 'System.String[]'.

Please advice.

Comment: @WP_Geek - All I can "advise" is that you need to check the format of your original data. Your question only provided a bit of detail on the type contained in `ReportListQuery` - I had to make an educated guess with `new { Amount = 8, TagsReport = new [] { "Hotel", "Mobile" } },`. If your source data is in this format it should work. If not you need to let me know what the difference is. The only other thing to try is to put a `.ToArray()` after the `ReportListQuery` in the `ReportingData` query and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the correct "advice" at the correct time. Brilliant piece of code which made my day. :-)

Comment: @WP_Geek - No worries. I'm glad I could "advise" you with the correct "advice". ;-)